# How to create links that have a dynamic url prefix?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

In my project, I have two routes that show the same component.

```
<Switch>
        <Route path="/one" component={Example}></Route>
        <Route path="/two" component={Example}></Route>
</Switch>
```

What I want to have happen is make a `Link` component in `path="/one"` lead to `/one/example` and `path="/two"` lead to `/two/example`.

However, I can't use react-router's `basename` prop because not all links will have the same prefix.

Currently, I'm passing in a `urlPrefix` prop and manually appending it to every `Link to=`. This is not a very clean solution and involves drilling props deep into the component tree.

```
<Route
  path="/one"
  render={props => < Example {...props} urlPrefix="/one" />}
/>
```

Does anyone have a good, DRY solution to this issue?